# Can the HP Officejet Pro 8600 scan to PDF without being hooked up to a computer?

Tags: scanner

I'm looking at buying an HP Officejet 8600. Can the HP Officejet Pro 8600 scan to PDF without being hooked up to a computer? Will I be able to pop in a flash drive and hit scan, and then run off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the 8600 can Scan to a Memory card. [Go to this link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/pfinder?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&tool=&query=office%20jet%20pro%208600), choose your model and then click "manuals" icon, then download the user guide

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Just what I'm looking for, I know the earlier Cannons required you to have a computer hooked up and the proprietary software package installed.

Comment: This type of HP printer runs palm OS, so the interface on the printer has some really nice features.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it scans to PDF?

Comment: I'm just trying to weight out the 8600 vs the PIXMA MX892 in scanning functionality. I hate that all these printers features are dependent on software bundles. If ADF can't save to a memory stick it's damn near useless to me.

Comment: Did you download and read the user guide? I believe all HP multifunctions with scanners scan to jpg, tiff, or pdf at a minimum